# How to JOIN a table with another table with only 1 common value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
ABC1234    GTR    some information    01/03/07    some information    0.55 
ABC1234    GTR    some information    14/11/18    some information    0.45 
ABC1234    GTR    some information    14/11/18    some information    0.45 
ABC1234    GTR    some information    22/11/18    some information    0.55
```

and another table:

```
ABC1234   3   39448.940091 
ABC1234   3   30806.72651    
ABC1234   3   14817.730764 
ABC1234   3   13482.769
```

I want to add the 4 decimal values at the end of the 2nd table into the first table but when I run my query:

```
select ta.column1, ta.column2, ta.column3, ta.column4, ta.column5, ta.column6, tb.column3  
from table_a ta,
table_b tb
where ta.column1, = tb.column1
and cd.contract_number = 'ABC1234';
```

I'm wanting to end up with:

```
ABC1234    GTR    some information    01/03/07    some information    0.55   39448.940091 
ABC1234    GTR    some information    14/11/18    some information    0.45   30806.72651 
ABC1234    GTR    some information    14/11/18    some information    0.45   14817.730764 
ABC1234    GTR    some information    22/11/18    some information    0.55   13482.769
```

but I'm getting 16 rows of data where it is looping round table_b and showing the 4 values for each row in table_a

Comment: why there is a comma in where?

Comment: You need an additional key to match the rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so it is not clear what rows match to what rows.

Comment: *"You need an additional key to match the rows. SQL tables represent unordered sets, so it is not clear what rows match to what rows."* true @GordonLinoff one could use `ROW_NUMBER()` on the date or simulate it using MySQl user variable but the results would still be non derministic (random) sometimes as the dates are not unique in the data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is not ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.

I can speculate that in the first table, the fourth column is intended as a date (hint:  you should use yyyy-mm-dd format) and that orders the rows.  And in the second table, they are ordered by the third column descending.

If so, you can combine them.  This is simpler to express in MySQL 8+:

```
select ta.column1, ta.column2, ta.column3, ta.column4, ta.column5, ta.column6, tb.column3  
from (select ta.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column4) as seqnum
      from table_a ta
     ) ta join
     (select tb.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column3 desc) as seqnum
      from table_b tb
     ) tb
     on ta.column1 = tb.column1 and ta.seqnum = tb.seqnum
where cd.contract_number = 'ABC1234';
```

You can do this in earlier versions but the calculation  of `seqnum` there is most easily done using variables.

Comment: *"SQL tables represent unordered sets. There is not ordering unless a column specifies the ordering."* Even with this approach, results will still be non derministic (random)  for possible duplicated dates like `14/11/18`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select ta.column1, ta.column2, ta.column3, ta.column4, ta.column5, ta.column6, tb.column3  
from table_a ta inner join
table_b tb on ta.column1 = tb.column1
where cd.contract_number = 'ABC1234';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to current situation column one of both the table have same entry. If you join with this then first row of table one with produce 4 row with join of table two. That's why you are getting 16 rows.
So you should create another column in both the table. Both column must be unique in your case. 
After that join on the base on new column.

I have added in last.

**table_a**

```
ABC1234    GTR    some information    01/03/07    some information    0.55   1
ABC1234    GTR    some information    14/11/18    some information    0.45   2
ABC1234    GTR    some information    14/11/18    some information    0.45   3
ABC1234    GTR    some information    22/11/18    some information    0.55   4
```

**table_b**

```
ABC1234   3   39448.940091     1
ABC1234   3   30806.72651      2
ABC1234   3   14817.730764     3
ABC1234   3   13482.769        4
```

**query**

```
select ta.column1, ta.column2, ta.column3, ta.column4, ta.column5, ta.column6, tb.column3 from table_a ta, table_b tb where ta.column7 = tb.column4;
```